# jenkins job for protractor cucumber

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, protractor

I have a protractor cucumber intellij project. I want to create a jenkins job that can run my tests. I have no idea how to do it. I could not find any tutorials that explain where to start from. Do I need to install a plugin or what exactly?

Comment: the starting point would be to see how you run your test now. See what exact command it uses, see what input it needs. Next you can put those commands as part of Jenkins job. You can choose to use gulp or grunt per your convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to successfully run from CLI now, Creating a Jenkins Job should be cake walk

1. Step 1 - Create a new job in Jenkins with build step as - execute shell
   To make life easy you can also install this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Batch+Task+Plugin)
2. Step 2: Assuming you are running the cucumber - protractor tests by configuring the cucumber as custom framework and providing the specs from conf.js like below

   `framework: 'custom',
   frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    cucumberOpts : {
     require : './features/LoginDefinitions.js',
     format  : 'pretty'
    }`
3. Step 3- Create a .bat file to trigger protractor -cucumber tests and point this batch file from Jenkins job

`echo 'started execution'
protractor protractor.conf.js`

//In Jenkins execute shell build step

```
C:\<<path>>\startExecution.bat
```